# AngularJS : css manipulation fails inside transcluded directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I am using angularjs 1.3.15

I created a simple directive like this:

```
myModule.directive('myContainerDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
        };
```

And another directive to be transcluded:

```
myModule.directive('myTranscludedDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<span id="myId" style="left: 2px;">THING</span>',
            compile: function (element, attributes) {

                var myChildCompile = angular.element(element.children()[0]);

                return {

                    post: function (scope, element, attributes) {

                         var myChildPostLink = angular.element(element.children()[0]);

                         //CASE 1: this will work if this directive isn't transcluded
                         myChildCompile.on("click", testHandler);

                         //CASE 2: this work in either case (transcluded or not)
                         myChildPostLink.on("click", testHandler);


                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I use them like this (only works for CASE 2):

```
<div my-container-directive>
    <my-transcluded-directive></my-transcluded-directive>
</div>
```

and this (works for CASE 1 and 2):

```
<div>
    <my-transcluded-directive></my-transcluded-directive>
</div>
```

It took me forever to figure out what the problem was.

Am I missing something here?

Why does using the variable defined in the compile section not work when the directive is transcluded via the containing directive?

Is this a bug in Angular?

I'm guessing that transclusion clones the template, so myChildCompile is not object being used in the link in that case, ie translusion case?

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?